# How to add new items to the Add New Item to project context menu in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

How can I add my own templates to the list of elements that appear in the Visual Studio 2010 Add context menu?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: please take a look at here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s365byhx(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can do in visual studio 2010 in following way:

```
1.Right click on the Tool menu and click "Customize..".
2.Click the "Commands" tab.
3.Click the "Context menu" option.
4.Select the "Project and Solution Context Menus | Solution".
5.Click the "Add Command..." button.
6.Select "File" in the "Categories" list box.
7.Select "Close Solution" in the "Commands" list box.
8.Move up/down as desired.
9.Click "Close".
```

Comment: Even when the answer points in the right direction it is related with Solution and not project elements. I don't find any command into the Project Category to add my own templates ...